# Active Directory vbscript case conversion

Tags: vbscript, lowercase, string-length, title-case

I need some help with my script.

The full script can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51160092/vbscript-remove-image-and-table-formatting)

The portion of the script I need help with is this:

```
If (Len(strTitle) > 3) Then
    arrStr = Split(strTitle," ")
    For i=0 To UBound(arrStr)
        word = LCase(Trim(arrStr(i)))
        word = Replace(word, Mid(word, 1, 1), UCase(Mid(word, 1, 1)), 1, 1)
        strTitleCon = strTitleCon & word & " "
    Next
End If
```

In our AD, everything is written in uppercase which is why I need to make it title case. However, this doesn't work if it's for title's like "QC Technician" or "HR Manager".

How can I go about doing that with the current script that I have?

Answer (score 0):

Add another condition inside the loop and change the casing only if the string is longer than 2 characters.

```
For i=0 To UBound(arrStr)
    word = Trim(arrStr(i))
    If Len(word) > 2 Then
        word = UCase(Left(word, 1)) & LCase(Mid(word, 2))
    End If
    arrStr(i) = word
Next
strTitleCon = Join(arrStr, " ")
```